# MySql query for a view in relational database

Tags: mysql

I have a problem to build MySQL query for a view. Below is my relational database structure and some sample data.

```
travel
| ID | NUM |
| 01 | N01 |
| 02 | N02 |

travel_has_flight
| travel_ID | flight_ID |
|    01     |     01    |
|    01     |     02    |
|    02     |     03    |

flight
| ID | NUM |  DEPARTURE_DATE  |   ARRIVAL_DATE   |
| 01 | A01 | 2010-10-10 12:50 | 2010-10-10 17:50 |
| 02 | A02 | 2010-10-17 14:50 | 2010-10-17 14:50 |
| 03 | A03 | 2010-10-22 12:50 | 2010-10-22 17:50 |
```

**Expected output:**

From query as view.

```
| travel_ID | travel_NUM | flight_NUM1 | flight_DEPARTURE_DATE | flight_NUM2 | flight_ARRIVAL_DATE |
|    01     |    N01     |    A01      |    2010-10-10 12:50   |     A02     |   2010-10-17 14:50  |
|    02     |    N02     |    A03      |    2010-10-10 12:50   |     A03     |   2010-10-17 14:50  |
```

The output should be as follows. Travel can contain 1 flight. In this case the output is data from travel + dates from this one flight. If travel contains 2 flight it should return data from travel + outbound date from 1st flight and inbound date from 2nd flight.

I will be glad for any help on this.

**### update ###**

I am stuck currently with below SQL, the question is how to add now separate flight_NUM's...

```
SELECT t.ID, t.NUM, Min(f.DEPARTURE_DATE), MAX(f.ARRIVAL_DATE)
FROM travel t
INNER JOIN travel_has_flight tf ON tf.TRAVEL_ID = t.ID
INNER JOIN flight f ON f.ID = tf.FLIGHT_ID
GROUP BY t.NUM
```

Comment: Do you work for an airline company or is this homework?

Comment: Trying to upgrade my 3rd party billing system to fit my needs?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are few ways to do it. I'd do an UNION of two selects, like this:

```
SELECT `travel`.`ID` as 'TRAVEL_ID',`travel`.`NUM` as 'TRAVEL_NUM', `flight`.`NUM` as 'FLIGHT_NUM1',`flight`.`DEPARTURE_DATE`as 'FLIGHT_DEPARTURE_DATE',`flight`.`NUM`as 'FLIGHT_NUM2',`flight`.`ARRIVAL_DATE`as 'FLIGHT_ARRIVAL_DATE'
FROM `travel`
INNER JOIN `travel_has_flight` on `travel`.`ID`=`travel_has_flight`.`travel_ID`
INNER JOIN `flight` on `travel_has_flight`.`flight_ID`=`flight`.`ID`
WHERE `travel`.ID in (SELECT travel_ID FROM `travel_has_flight` GROUP BY travel_ID HAVING count(`flight_ID`)=1)
UNION
SELECT T.TRAVEL_ID,T.TRAVEL_NUM,MIN(T.FLIGHT_NUM1),MIN(T.FLIGHT_DEPARTURE_DATE),MAX(T.FLIGHT_NUM2),MAX(T.FLIGHT_ARRIVAL_DATE)
FROM 
(SELECT `travel`.`ID` as 'TRAVEL_ID',`travel`.`NUM` as 'TRAVEL_NUM', `flight`.`NUM` as 'FLIGHT_NUM1',`flight`.`DEPARTURE_DATE`as 'FLIGHT_DEPARTURE_DATE',`flight`.`NUM`as 'FLIGHT_NUM2',`flight`.`ARRIVAL_DATE`as 'FLIGHT_ARRIVAL_DATE'
FROM `travel`
INNER JOIN `travel_has_flight` on `travel`.`ID`=`travel_has_flight`.`travel_ID`
INNER JOIN `flight` on `travel_has_flight`.`flight_ID`=`flight`.`ID`
WHERE `travel`.ID in (SELECT travel_ID FROM `travel_has_flight` GROUP BY travel_ID HAVING count(`flight_ID`)>1)) as T
GROUP BY T.TRAVEL_ID,T.TRAVEL_NUM
```

Comment: Thanks for advise. I will try it later on.

Comment: Thank you it works for me ... in MySql MariaDB 10.1.21 .. not in 10.1.19 which I had.

Answer (score 0):

Your tables are,

```
table travel ( ID int, NUM varchar() )
table leg (travel_ID int, flight_ID )
table flight ( ID int, NUM varchar(), DEPARTURE date, ARRIVAL date )
```

join travel with leg, join leg with flight,

```
select <more below>
from travel t
<how> join leg l where t.ID = l.travel_ID
<how> join flight f where l.flight_ID == f.ID
```

Now, decide whether these are inner or outer joins?

Do you want results even when join between travel and travel_has_flight (leg) have no match? If no, then use inner join, if yes, then use outer join. (important for your sample data)

Do you want results even when join between travel_has_flight (leg) and flight have no match? If no, then use inner join, if yes, then use outer join. (does not matter for your sample data)

You said use inner joins,

```
select <more below>
from travel t
inner join leg l where t.ID = l.travel_ID
inner join flight f where l.flight_ID == f.ID
```

On your sample data, the resulting set is,

```
t. | t.  | l.        | l.        | f. | f.  | f.               | f.
ID | NUM | travel_ID | flight_ID | ID | NUM | DEPARTURE        | ARRIVAL
01 | N01 | 01        | 01        | 01 | A01 | 2010-10-10 12:50 | 2010-10-10   17:50
01 | N01 | 01        | 02        | 02 | A02 | 2010-10-17 14:50 | 2010-10-17   14:50 
02 | N02 | 02        | 03        | 03 | A03 | 2010-10-22 12:50 | 2010-10-22   17:50
```

But, you said use inner joins, so you are looking for 1:1 
You need this data ordered by dates. Assume sane data (DEPARTURE <= ARRIVAL)

```
with (
select t.ID as tid, t.NUM as tnum, f.DEPARTURE as dep, f.ARRIVAL as arr
from travel t
inner join leg l where t.ID = l.travel_ID
inner join flight f where l.flight_ID == f.ID
group by t.NUM
order by t.NUM, DEPARTURE
) as parts,
<query>
```

Now, how would you combine the two rows in the above 'parts' table to connect the parts?

Comment: Thank you for explanation. In my case I was using mariadb 10.1.19 and it was not able to work on nested tables/subqueries. Updatingg to 10.1.21 fixed the problem with the queries.